# SparkStream: Convert String to Float in SQL Query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert **String to Float in a Spark Stream SQL Query**.

However, I am not able to do so. Can someone please help.

Code for my conversion is:

```
       dataFrame
        .select($"payment".cast("float"))
        .filter($"modeOfPayment" =!= "")
        .show()
```

.cast() method is not working to Convert String to Float for me.
Any help will be appreciated.

I am running:
**Spark Version: 2.3.0** 
**Scala Version: 2.11.11**

Comment: Not clear what is not worked. Such code worked fine:     val dataFrame = List("12.30", "11.40").toDF("payment"); 
    dataFrame.select($"payment".cast("float")).show()

Comment: Your code should work fine. Check schema of the dataframe (dataFrame.printSchema()) before casting and I believe that must be different than StringType which might cause you exception.

Comment: I checked the incoming schema of this dataframe. It is like =>                              |-- payment: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modeOfPayment: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Whether I cast this StringType to Integer or Float, it just does not convert. Can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using the following syntax:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.FloatType

dataFrame
  .withColumn("payment", dataFrame("payment") cast FloatType)
  .show()
```

**The filter statement is not working though.** Might need some help with it.